# Upload a text File from .Net http client to Java REST API in InputStream format

Tags: java, .net, rest, file, httpclient

I have a case where I want to upload a text File from .Net http client to Java REST API in InputStream format. When I hit the Java REST from Postman with File in Form-Data Body, the file is getting received in Java REST service perfectly fine. When I try is same thing from the .Net Client, i have getting some exceptions as below.

My .Net HTTP Client code is as below,

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8082/processes/view/createDocumentfromFile/851");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("procId", "100");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DocName", "ProphetWorkflow");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\charan.ghate\Desktop\Calculation.txt")));
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;
if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    lblResponse.Text = result;
}
```

My Java REST Service Code is as below,

```
@POST
@Path("/createDocumentfromFile/{procId}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response createDocumentfromFile(@PathParam("procId") Long piOID, @HeaderParam("DocName") String modulename,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
//
//Operation on the input stream
//
}
```

When I hit a REST API, I have getting the exception at both the side in .Net as well as In Java, detailed below

.Net Error Message:

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2016 15:08:03 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.
```

Java exception:

```
    Dec 23, 2016 8:38:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cxf-jaxrs-servlet] in context with path [/ipp-portal] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:503)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.stardust.ui.web.html5.EnhancedJarResourceFilter.doFilter(EnhancedJarResourceFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.TouchSessionFilter.doFilter(TouchSessionFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could you please suggest me the best way to transfer a file from .Net Client to Java REST Service.

Answer (score 2):

The exception

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;

means that it tries to get a method at runtime of type `Response validate(final Response response, Response.Status.Family expectedStatusFamily)` from the class `ClientErrorException` that it cannot find.

This generally happens when you build your application with one version of your library and you run it against a different version that is not compatible.

Knowing that this method has been added since `JAX-RS 2.0`, I believe that you compiled your code with `JAX-RS 2.0` or higher and you have a version `1.x` in your classpath that is used instead at Runtime. Check the classpath used at Runtime and ensure that you have only the same version of the `JAX-RS` that you used at Compile time.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that the server does not like the request, prepare to send an error, and fails because of a library mismatch (as pointed by Nicolas Filotto). This is why you are seeing a generic HTTP 500 error instead of some (more informative) 4XX.

Resolve the library version mismatch is probably a good idea, even if it works when the request matches what the server expects (as showed with Postman)

Looking at the signatures on both sides, this is what I could think of :

- add  `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE` to the consumed content types.
- remove `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("procId", "100");`, as the `procId` is expected on the path, not in the headers.
- add `file` as name of the `ByteArrayContent` :

  ```
  content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\charan.ghate\Desktop\Calculation.txt")), "file");
  ```

Additionally you can try to disable the `Expect: 100-continue` header used by default by the .NET `HttpClient`, some servers don't handle it.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```